# How to create new course on Openedx?

Tags: openedx

I have a new instance of openedx with no course.
I logged into it, but I cannot create course. Seems I can only consult them.

What to do to create a course on a new openedx instance ?

Answer (score 3):

**To create a course, follow these steps.**

- Sign in to your Open edX instance Studio.
- Select New Course.
- Enter the following information about your course.

*Important
The values that you enter for the organization, course number, and course run cannot be edited after you create your course.*

For Course Name, enter the title of your course. For example, the name might be “Sets, Maps, and Symmetry Groups”. Use title capitalization for the course title, and normal spacing and punctuation.

For Organization, you enter the identifier for your organization. Do not include spaces or special characters.

For Course Number, you enter both a subject abbreviation and a number. For example, for public health course number 207, enter PH207. For math course 101x, enter Math101x. Do not include spaces or special characters in the course number.

*Note
If your course will be public, be sure to include the “x”. If it is exclusively an on campus offering, do not include the “x”.*

For Course Run, you enter the term in which your course will run. For example, enter 2014SOND or T2_2014. Do not include spaces or special characters.

The value that you enter for the run does not affect the course start date that you define for the course. For more information, see Setting Start and End Dates.

The organization, course number, and course run values that you enter are used to create the URL for your course. Because URLs do not have an unlimited length, the total number of characters that you enter for these values must be 65 or fewer.

Select **Create**.

The Course Outline page opens. You can start developing course content. For more information, see Getting Started with Course Content Development.

More http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/open-edx-ca/en/latest/set_up_course/creating_new_course.html#create-a-course

Answer (score 1):

[5.1. Creating a Course](http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/open-edx-ca/en/latest/set_up_course/creating_new_course.html#creating-a-course) is your anwser.